# vuejs 3 composition api getCurrentInstance($refs)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a problem

I can access $ref in onmounted function but
note : getCurrentInstance imported
I am getting the following error in submit function

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ctx')

```
const submit = () => {
  getCurrentInstance().ctx.$refs.modalLoading.openModal()
}
onMounted(() => {
  getCurrentInstance().ctx.$refs.modalLoading.closeModal()
})
```

Comment: getCurrentInstance don't always return a value, you will have to check if you got the instance  before using it.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what should I do @Lk77

Comment: Use a if statement like : `let instance = getCurrentInstance(); if(instance) { instance.ctx ... }`

Comment: getCurrentInstance() call should always be in setup function/block. It's obvious that there's no instance when a component is unmounted. Could be another hook (onBeforeUnmount)

Comment: Normally you should not use `getCurrentInstance` as it is not officially mentioned in the documentation and might not be stable. You can directly assign refs to ref variables and use these variables. See: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `getCurrentInstance` should normally not been used, you should follow the [Template Refs guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html).

```html
<!—- inside the template —->
<my-modal ref="modalLoading" />
```

```js
// your component
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const modalLoading = ref(null);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
      If(!modalLoading.value) return;
      modalLoading.value.openModal();
    }

    return { modalLoading };

  }
})
```